# Why elasticsearch matchQuery does not return results?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have successfully indexed content with elasticsearch, but I am having troubles when trying to query content.

What I want to do is to search **all docs** that both contains value "**ipsum**" (in any of it's terms) **AND** term "type" should be equal to "cq:Page".

I am using High Level Rest Java Client. Tried with filtering and with Boolquery but it returns zero results.

Example:

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.from(0);
sourceBuilder.size(10);

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
searchRequest.indices("gettingstarted");
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
                boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("ipsum"));
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("type", "cq:Page"));
sourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);


SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Data looks like this:

```
{ 
   "took":4,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{ 
      "total":1,
      "successful":1,
      "skipped":0,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{ 
      "total":{ 
         "value":1,
         "relation":"eq"
      },
      "max_score":1.0,
      "hits":[ 
         { 
            "_index":"gettingstarted",
            "_type":"_doc",
            "_id":"2",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{ 
               "docs":[ 
                  { 
                     "id":"/content/we-retail/us/en/community/members",
                     "type":"cq:Page",
                     "jcr_title":"Members",
                     "jcr:created":"java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1564730906165,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=false,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=\"GMT+02:00\",offset=7200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=31,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_YEAR=214,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=28,SECOND=26,MILLISECOND=165,ZONE_OFFSET=7200000,DST_OFFSET=0]",
                     "cq:lastModified":"java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1518654268630,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=false,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=\"GMT-05:00\",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=7,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=14,DAY_OF_YEAR=45,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=19,MINUTE=24,SECOND=28,MILLISECOND=630,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=0]",
                     "manualCreationDate":"2019-09-05T13:21:00.000+02:00",
                     "jcr:primaryType":"cq:PageContent",
                     "sling:resourceType":"social/console/components/basepage",
                     "searchDescription":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sportsman delighted improving dashwoods gay instantly happiness six. Ham now amounted absolute not mistaken way pleasant whatever. At an these still no dried folly stood thing. Rapid it on hours hills it seven years. If polite he active county in spirit an. Mrs ham intention promotion engrossed assurance defective. Confined so graceful building opinions whatever trifling in. Insisted out differed ham man endeavor expenses. At on he total their he songs. Related compact effects is on settled do.",
                     "pageImportanceRank":"4"
                  }, ...
```

Tried this also but without a success, it returns zero results.

```
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("type", NT_PAGE));
```

Comment: Please share your mappings

Comment: There are many conditions in between, but I've added some simplified ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with using **matchPhraseQuery** instead of matchQuery.
My value was "cp:Page".

In this case matchQuery returns the document only if this term has exactly the same value as it is in it's index (and at the query time there are **no analyzers used**).

On the other hand, **matchPhraseQuery will use default analyzers at the query time as well** so value in query will be the same as indexed value after analzsers change it.

> Analyzers can be specified per-query, per-field or per-index. At index time, Elasticsearch will look for an analyzer in this order:
>
> The analyzer defined in the field mapping. An analyzer named default
>   in the index settings. The standard analyzer. At query time, there are
>   a few more layers:
>
> The analyzer defined in a full-text query. The search_analyzer defined
>   in the field mapping. The analyzer defined in the field mapping. An
>   analyzer named default_search in the index settings. An analyzer named
>   default in the index settings. The standard analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "ipsum",
            "fields": []
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "cq:Page"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

"fields": [] -> meaning all fields
```

Comment: What is the difference here from my query? I tried with Java but it was not successful.

Comment: I'm using multi_match query string. try QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(your text)

Comment: Yes, but the thing this that even this boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("type", NT_PAGE)); returns zero results.

Comment: where NT_PAGE stands for "cq:Page". I've also tried cq\\:Page, but result is the same

Comment: If you run my query via kibana do you get any results?

Comment: I've found solution. It was about analyzers changing the indexed value. Thank you for the help